# Is the sentence "The parents then strongly requested the government to assist students stayed in the airport." correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I read it in Wikipedia (it read that way from [08:31, 15 February 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hong_Kong_Kids_phenomenon&oldid=595562401) to [17:48, 20 December 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hong_Kong_Kids_phenomenon&oldid=931710649)) but it sounds wrong to me. Here is the sentence in context:

> For instance, in 2010, the Hong Kong students could not get on the planes because of a snowstorm in London. The parents then strongly requested the government to assist students **stayed in the airport.** This issue induced a lot of criticisms towards parents because of their over-protection.

Shouldn't it be either "the students that stayed" or "the students staying"?

Edit (Dec. 22, 2019): the [current version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Kids_phenomenon) reads *stranded at the airport*, but the question about the acceptability of the old version, *stayed in the airport*, remains.

Comment: It could be correct if "stayed" is referring to people who were issued orders to stay somewhere.  But it's probably a tupo.

Comment: You can fix it in Wikipedia.

Comment: @HotLicks Is tupo a pun, then?

Comment: *Stayed*: held back; could also mean "detained," "given accommodation". Also @DJClayworth Whoa!

Comment: @Kris - "tupo" is the way "typo" *should* be spelled.

Comment: This is a misquote; 'This article has multiple issues. Please help improve it or discuss these issues on the talk page' is a vital part of the full quote.

Comment: @Kris 'Stayed [v tr] could also mean "detained," "given accommodation" ' Reference? Caveats (eg 'obsolete')?

Comment: "The parents then strongly requested the government to assist students **stranded** at the airport". **You misquoted it**. It's fine like it is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was misquoted from a Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Lambie I edited the question to address your concerns.

Comment: @linguisticturn I think that to answer this question, one needs to first reproduce in full all the relevant sentences rather than non-pertinent chunks of them. Then,what is grammatical or not becomes **very clear**.  That would lay it out clearly. Because: stayed at the airport and stranded at the airport, per se, are fine. So, the question continues to be invalid *as posed*, but in any case does not require a full-blown treatise.

Comment: @Lambie Very well, done (as far as the question). As far as my answer, I have deleted the other entries from the OED; it indeed doesn't look like they are needed. My answer is considerably shorter now.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  When I wrote this question the sentence was the way I quoted it. Since then, it has been changed. You may check the Wikipedia article history.

Comment: No; a misquote is any quote that leaves out information necessary for a complete assessment of what is being said. All editions on Wikipedia contain the caveat 'This article has multiple issues. Please help improve ...' or equivalent which you also should have included, to aid readers' judgement. I haven't mentioned the correction they've later made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full context is that there were a number of students from Hong Kong who were traveling back to Hong Kong from London's Heathrow airport, but whose flights were canceled due to a snowstorm in London. Given this, the most natural and standard way to phrase it is that they were

***stranded at*** the airport

See e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=fWYf2b65ODEC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA26&dq=%22stranded%20at%20the%20airport%22&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q=%22stranded%20at%20the%20airport%22&f=false). And indeed, that was the phrasing used in a [press release](https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/201012/20/P201012200253.htm) by the Hong Kong government at the time.

Having said all that, I should note that it is not actually wrong to use *stayed*. The OED does record one of its transitive meanings as

> To detain, hold back, stop (a person or thing); to check or arrest the progress of, bring to a halt; to hinder from going on or going away; to keep in a fixed place or position. Now only *literary*.

However, while it is not wrong, it is arguably a bad choice for usage in the text of a Wikipedia article, where the context definitely isn't literary.

**Discussion**

The version with *stayed at the airport* comes from a [recent](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hong_Kong_Kids_phenomenon&oldid=931710649) (but, as of the time of my writing, revised) version of the Wikipedia article 'Hong Kong Kids phenomenon':

> For instance, in 2010, the Hong Kong students could not get on the planes because of a snowstorm in London. The parents then strongly requested the government to assist students **stayed** in the airport.

The text on Wikipedia that is [current as of the time of this writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hong_Kong_Kids_phenomenon&oldid=931722675) has been changed and it reads *stranded at the airport* (possibly as a result the first version of this very answer).

The text on Wikipedia seems to be a summary of original text in Chinese. Unfortunately, the linked web page (in Chinese) no longer seems to have that text. Therefore, we don't know what the original Chinese text actually said.

However, there is a [press release](https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/201012/20/P201012200253.htm) from the Hong Kong government, dated December 20, 2010,  that seems to be about this event and whose first paragraph reads,

> The Government is very concerned about Hong Kong students **stranded** at Heathrow Airport, London, due to snowstorm and would proactively offer assistance with a view to bringing them home, the Under Secretary for Security, Mr Lai Tung-kwok, said today (December 20).

***Stayed***

The version with *stayed* is not actually wrong. It used in the sense of *the students who were stayed*, i.e. in the passive voice. The active voice version would be *[the snowstorm] stayed the students.* The OED records the following meaning of the verb *stay* (I only reproduce the most recent examples of usage that the OED provides):

> III. *transitive.* To stop, arrest, check.
>   **20.**
>   **a.** To detain, hold back, stop (a person or thing); to check or arrest the progress of, bring to a halt; to hinder from going on or going away; to keep in a fixed place or position. Now only *literary*.
>   
>   <sup>…
>
>   1830   Ld. Tennyson *Poems* 96   Thou shalt not wander hence to-night, I'll **stay** thee with my kisses.
>
>   1873   A. Helps *Some Talk about Animals & their Masters* vi. 152   Among the reeds, where, at the moment,
>
>                                                                                                                                                          we had **stayed** the boat.
>
>   1902   *Munsey's Mag.* **26** 596/1   Attacking and withdrawing again before any force could be mobilized to **stay** him.</sup>

However, given the setting of a Wikipedia article, this literary usage is probably not a good choice.

**Choice of preposition**

If one chooses to use *stay*, there is still the issue of what preposition should be used, since its choice depends on the verb and also on the precise meaning one wishes to convey. I have been unable to find any examples of usage of *stay* as a transitive verb + preposition + *airport*, which is not surprising given how rare this transitive usage of *stay* is. For what it's worth, to my ear, given the context, *at* seems more appropriate than *in*, but I am sure *in* is also acceptable. Even in the case of *stranded*, the Corpus of Contemporary American English [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) does record two examples of *stranded **in** the airport*. True, this should be compared to the 14 examples of *stranded **at** the airport*, but perhaps there are subtle differences in meaning. Google NGrams also shows that the version with *at* is about seven times more frequent than the version with *at* (see [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stranded+at+the+airport%2Cstranded+in+the+airport&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstranded%20at%20the%20airport%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstranded%20in%20the%20airport%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cstranded%20at%20the%20airport%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstranded%20in%20the%20airport%3B%2Cc0)).

I should also list the following examples of usage from published literature:

*Actually, the point of going there this time was to hang around for a while **in the airport,** so I planned a Las Vegas stopover on a return trip from a speaking engagement.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=PtpK-VPX6IAC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA93&dq=%22in%20the%20airport%22&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20airport%22&f=false)
*You must buy your ticket **in the airport** before you get on the shuttle train: 11 Euros one-way and 14.5 Euros roundtrip. They have an information booth **in the airport** that can steer you in the right direction.*  [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=_FceMLPzliwC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA93&dq=%22in%20the%20airport%22&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20airport%22&f=false)
*At one time, it seemed airport concessionaires literally banked on the fact that air travelers would pay exorbitant prices for last-minute souvenirs, gifts for kids, and even a pack of gum once they were **in the airport.***  [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=K6dQlWZ7PeYC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA14&dq=%22in%20the%20airport%22&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20airport%22&f=false)

Comment: See also my comment at the OP.

Comment: Stay me with flagons. I suppose it's valid, given that ELU sees questions as a way to investigate, better understand, and find pronouncements on usages rather than as requests for 'the answer' per se. But it's still an error in the original, whether a miscopying, a slip in word choice, or a misunderstanding in word usage.

Comment: "The parents then strongly requested the government to assist students stranded at the airport". is the actual sentence on Wikipedia. Therefore, your answer is overkill.

Comment: @Lambie 1. As I said in my answer, yes, that is the actual sentence on Wikipedia now. But as recently as [17:48, 20 December 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hong_Kong_Kids_phenomenon&oldid=931710649), it read *stayed in the airport*, and it had been that way since [08:31, 15 February 2014‎](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hong_Kong_Kids_phenomenon&oldid=931710649). (I doubt it's a coincidence it got changed back to *stranded* right after I posted my answer.) 2. What matters is not what Wikipedia says, but what the question asks about English usage.

Comment: I disagree when the question misquotes something. I can't be bothered with all these details. Today, 22 December 2019, it is misquoted.

Comment: Well done. You’ve brought out an interesting aspect of the English used in the question. +1